# How to make the Tkinter GUI not crash when executing a long function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am currently working on a program, built with Python and Tkinter to interact with different instruments in our lab and to test some electronic devices. There I have a function (isDutAlive()) which can take really long (up to 10-15 minutes) until the function finishes.
Now the Tkinter GUI is not responding during this time and to the user it looks like the program has crashed. Also no other operations are possible.
Here is the code:

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import pyvisa
import time
from datetime import datetime
import threading
from jsonrpcclient import request
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

print("-----------------------------------------")
print("              Q-Center V0.1              ")
print("-----------------------------------------")

port = ":8080"
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()



def listArticles():
    #print("PK IP Address: ")
    #pkIpAddress = input()
    response = request("http://" + ipEntry.get() + port, "temperature_test_list_articles")
    print(response.text)
    print(response.data.result)
    answer = response.data.result
    pkReply.insert(END, answer)
    pkReply.insert(END, '\n\n')

def setArticle():
    response = request("http://" + ipEntry.get() + port,  "temperature_test_set_article", articleEntry.get())
    print(response.text)
    print(response.data.result)
    answer = response.text
    pkReply.insert(END, answer)
    pkReply.insert(END, '\n\n')

def unsetArticle():
    response = request("http://" + ipEntry.get() + port,  "temperature_test_unset_article")
    print(response.text)
    print(response.data.result)
    answer = response.text
    pkReply.insert(END, answer)
    pkReply.insert(END, '\n\n')

def clearLog():
    pkReply.delete('1.0', END)

def listInstruments():
    instruments = rm.list_resources()
    print(instruments)
    print('\n\n')
    visaReplyText.insert(END, instruments)
    visaReplyText.insert(END, '\n\n')
    return 0

def isDutAlive():
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S.txt")
    logFile = open(timestamp, "a")
    logFile.write("Timestamp               DUT     Result       Voltage         Current\n\n")
    for x in range (int(firstSocketEntry.get()), int(lastSocketEntry.get())+1):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
        response = request("http://" + ipEntry.get() + port, "temperature_test_is_dut_alive", x)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(response.text)
        print(response.data.result)
        answer = response.data.result
        pkReply.insert(END, answer)
        pkReply.insert(END, '\n\n')
        logFile.write(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S\t\t") + str(x) + "\t\t" + str(answer) + "\t\t" + str(readVoltage()) + "\t\t" + str(readCurrent()) + "\n")  
    print("TEST")

def clearPyvisaLog():
    visaReplyText.delete('1.0', END)
    return 0

def readVoltage():
    choosenInstrument = rm.open_resource(instrumentEntry.get())
    voltageMeasurement = choosenInstrument.query_ascii_values("MEAS:VOLT? (@" + setChannelEntry.get() + ")")
    visaReplyText.insert(END, voltageMeasurement)
    visaReplyText.insert(END, " V")
    visaReplyText.insert(END, "\n\n")
    return voltageMeasurement

def readCurrent():
    choosenInstrument = rm.open_resource(instrumentEntry.get())
    currentMeasurement = choosenInstrument.query_ascii_values("MEAS:CURR? (@" + setChannelEntry.get() + ")")
    visaReplyText.insert(END, currentMeasurement)
    visaReplyText.insert(END, " A")
    visaReplyText.insert(END, "\n\n")
    return currentMeasurement

def setVoltage():
    choosenInstrument = rm.open_resource(instrumentEntry.get())
    print(choosenInstrument.query('*IDN?'))
    print(choosenInstrument.write("VOLT:LEV " + setVoltageEntry.get() + ", (@" + setChannelEntry.get() + ")"))
    return 0


def setCurrent():
    choosenInstrument = rm.open_resource(instrumentEntry.get())
    print(choosenInstrument.query('*IDN?'))
    print(choosenInstrument.write("CURR:LEV " + setCurrentEntry.get() + ", (@" + setChannelEntry.get() + ")"))
    return 0

def toggleChannelOutput():
    choosenInstrument = rm.open_resource(instrumentEntry.get())
    #choosenInstrument.write("OUTPut OFF, (@2)")
    choosenInstrument.write(output.get() + ", (@" + setChannelEntry.get() + ")")
    return 0

def sendRelayCommand():
    send = requests.get('http://' + relayIPEntry.get() + '/io.cgi?DO' + on_off.get() + relayNumberEntry.get())
    print(on_off.get())

def cycleRelay():
    send = requests.get('http://' + relayIPEntry.get() + '/io.cgi?DOI' + relayNumberEntry.get() + '=100')

root = Tk()
#root.geometry("800x400")
root.title("Q-Center")
root.iconbitmap("./icons/icon.ico")
root.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file='./icons/icon.png'))
# root.iconphoto(False, PhotoImage(file='./icons/icon.png'))

on_off = StringVar()
output = StringVar()

##############################################################################################################################

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text="PK Control")
tabControl.add(tab2, text="Keysight Control")
tabControl.add(tab3, text="Relay Board Control")
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

##############################################################################################################################

ipEntry = ttk.Entry(tab1)
ipEntry.pack()
ipEntry.insert(0, "192.168.1.73")

listArticlesButton = Button(tab1, text="List Articles", command=listArticles)
listArticlesButton.pack()

articleEntry = ttk.Entry(tab1)
articleEntry.pack()

setArticleButton = Button(tab1, text="Set Article", command=setArticle)
setArticleButton.pack()

unsetArticleButton = Button(tab1, text="Unset Article", command=unsetArticle)
unsetArticleButton.pack()

firstSocketTestLabel = Label(tab1, text="Enter First Socket To Test")
firstSocketTestLabel.pack()

firstSocketEntry = ttk.Entry(tab1)
firstSocketEntry.pack()

lastSocketTestLabel = Label(tab1, text="Enter Last Socket To Test")
lastSocketTestLabel.pack()

lastSocketEntry = ttk.Entry(tab1)
lastSocketEntry.pack()

isDutAliveButton = Button(tab1, text="Is DUT Alive", command=isDutAlive)
isDutAliveButton.pack()

clearLogEntryButton = Button(tab1, text="Clear Log", command=clearLog)
clearLogEntryButton.pack()

pkReply = Text(tab1)
pkReply.pack()

##############################################################################################################################

listInstrumentsButton = Button(tab2, text="List Instruments", command=listInstruments)
listInstrumentsButton.pack()

instrumentLabel = Label(tab2, text="Enter The Instruments VISA Address")
instrumentLabel.pack()

instrumentEntry = ttk.Entry(tab2)
instrumentEntry.pack()
instrumentEntry.insert(0, "USB0::0x0957::0x0C07::MY54005119::INSTR")

setVoltageLabel = Label(tab2, text="Enter The Voltage")
setVoltageLabel.pack()

setVoltageEntry = ttk.Entry(tab2)
setVoltageEntry.pack()

setCurrentLabel = Label(tab2, text="Enter The Current")
setCurrentLabel.pack()

setCurrentEntry = ttk.Entry(tab2)
setCurrentEntry.pack()

setChannelLabel = Label(tab2, text="Enter The Channel")
setChannelLabel.pack()

setChannelEntry = ttk.Entry(tab2)
setChannelEntry.pack()
setChannelEntry.insert(0, "2")

readVoltageButton = Button(tab2, text="Read Voltage", command=readVoltage)
readVoltageButton.pack()

readCurrentButton = Button(tab2, text="Read Current", command=readCurrent)
readCurrentButton.pack()

setVoltageButton = Button(tab2, text="Set Voltage", command=setVoltage)
setVoltageButton.pack()

setCurrentButton = Button(tab2, text="Set Current", command=setCurrent)
setCurrentButton.pack()

outputOnRadioButton = ttk.Radiobutton(tab2, variable=output, text="On", value="OUTPut ON", command=toggleChannelOutput)
outputOnRadioButton.pack()

relayOffRadioButton = ttk.Radiobutton(tab2, variable=output, text="Off", value="OUTPut OFF", command=toggleChannelOutput) 
relayOffRadioButton.pack()

clearLogButton = Button(tab2, text="Clear Log", command=clearPyvisaLog)
clearLogButton.pack()

visaReplyText = Text(tab2)
visaReplyText.pack()

##############################################################################################################################

relayIPLabel = ttk.Label(tab3, text="Relay Board IP")
relayIPLabel.pack()

relayIPEntry = ttk.Entry(tab3)
relayIPEntry.insert(0, "192.168.1.199")
relayIPEntry.pack()

relayNumberLabel = ttk.Label(tab3, text="Relay Number")
relayNumberLabel.pack()

relayNumberEntry = ttk.Entry(tab3)
relayNumberEntry.insert(0, "2")
relayNumberEntry.pack()

relayOnRadioButton = ttk.Radiobutton(tab3, variable=on_off, text="On", value="A") # A for active (turn on)
relayOnRadioButton.pack()

relayOffRadioButton = ttk.Radiobutton(tab3, variable=on_off, text="Off", value="I") # I for inactive (turn off)
relayOffRadioButton.pack()

sendRelayCommandButton = Button(tab3, text="Send Command", command=sendRelayCommand)
sendRelayCommandButton.pack()

cycleRelayButton = Button(tab3, text="Cycle Relay 10s", command=cycleRelay)
cycleRelayButton.pack()

##############################################################################################################################

root.mainloop()
```

Now I read that multithreading would be a suitable soloution but I am not sure how to implement this in the best way.
I tried to make a thread out of the function "isDutAlive()" and to start it after the button has been pushed which triggered the start of this thread. But when I want to push the button again (in order to execute the function and the test again), it tells me, that a thread can only be started once.
Is there a way to "kill" a thread after a funtion has been executed? Any suggestions how I can make the GUI responsive during the execution of this function?
I am thankful for any help and any hint. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are well on your way. Multithreading is indeed a way to solve this problem. You are essentially trying to do something asynchronous.

The quickest way might be to include threads like you mentioned. A good resource for that would be [this page on realpython.com](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/). Specifically on the topic of [barriers](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#barrier) or [deadlocks](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#deadlock) which I think answers your question.

Alternatively if you calculate this to be happening more and the results can be show X time later without the user still actively waiting for them is to use some sort of asynchronous system with a broker. The thing I used in a similar situation is [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html). I combined it with the easy to use RabbitMQ instance.

Using this setup your users will create "todo" tasks in a predefined queue which will then be handled. The output can be stored in a result queue where your application could subscribe to. There are some advantages and disadvantages to using this solution which may or may not be dealbreaking in your case.

Advantages:

1. Really asynchronous, so as long as your application can reach the RMQ server it should have next to 0 impact on your system and the GUI will always remain "up".
2. No matter how many times the users will press the button, it will not have to wait for results.

Disadvantages:

1. Each items will be executed separately. Putting 5 items on the queue means the same action will be executed 5 times.
2. There is need to extra software (RMQ or another broker) as well as extra libraries (celery)
3. Users will actively have to get the result of their actions. This might be a hurdle.

I hope I've given you some pointers to possible solutions?